# Is this a bug or a feature of ManagementScope?

Tags: c#, wmi, rpc

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.connectionoptions.aspx

```
ConnectionOptions co = new ConnectionOptions();
co.Username = CreateUserName(Domain, Username);
```

If I use the previous code together with ManagementScope like this:

```
ManagementScope ms = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + PcName + "\\root\\cimv2:Win32_Service='RpcSs'", co);
ms.Connect();
```

But if I use incorrect Domain it still works? How should I correct this. Why is this happening?

Edit 1: This happens(I am allowed with bad domain and correct Administrator account and correct password) when I try to access a remote machine, which may have other credentials and other domain than my machine.

Edit 2: Bad domain in my case means: domain which does not exist on that machine or other domain in which the current user entered is not present.

Edit 3:
Even if I use this code:

```
options.Authority = "ntlmdomain:DOMAIN";//this won't work either.
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.connectionoptions.authority.aspx

Comment: Why not? Imagine you try to connect to "\\pc-of-my-boss\documents", you'll be prompted to enter your credentials (they can be for local user, for domain or for anything allowed on target computer). If you provide wrong credentials simply you won't be able to log-in.

Comment: yes, but I am allowed to do a bunch of things like restart even though the credentials (especially the domain is wrong).

Comment: No, you won't be able to do more than what that user can do (according to his rights on target machine) minus what policies permit (especially in domains).

Comment: "...this happens..." what happens?

Comment: What do you mean with "bad domain"? A domain that doesn't exist for the target machine? A random domain name? What do you do exactly in CreateUserName() function? How can you have a valid administrator account (user name + password) but a wrong domain (users can be local or of domain but somewhere they must exist).

Comment: @Adriano check my second edit. Basically all the cases you mention in the comment.

Comment: Hmmmmm pretty!!! if you try with wbemtest you get same results?

Comment: what domain is this : wbemtest ?

Comment: It's a tool to test WMI (remote too).

Comment: @Adriano this works too. But only on local without credentials, on remote it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WbemTest is the standard to know how WMI behaves. Addressing your comment (@Floradu88, May 15):

> 1) WbemTest fails on remote connections when passing invalid credentials (invalid domain)

That is the expected behavior, of course

> 2) WbemTest for local connection works "only without credentials"

It looks like this might not have trickled up into the documentation for [ManagementScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementscope.aspx) and [ConnectionOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.connectionoptions.aspx), but:

> You cannot change credentials when connecting to the local computer.
>   (MSDN: [WMI Tasks: Connecting to the WMI Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394589.aspx))

> **Remarks**
>   Do not specify strUser, strPassword, or strAuthority when making a connection to a local namespace.
>   (MSDN: [IWbemLocator::ConnectServer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa391769.aspx))

---

Regarding your original question, because you have said that WbemTest is behaving as expected, we know that WMI is "working" and it's not an edge case issue like the target machine having been configured to accept anonymous connections.

One possibility is that your C# WMI connection is using the credentials of the calling user, rather than the specified (invalid) credentials. Please try running the same code, but this time as a user on the local machine whose account does not exist on the remote machine. If that fails, it means that the caller's credentials were being used instead of the explicit credentials you wanted. Which, if it occurred, would suggest an error in your implementation of the calls to impersonate the manually specified credentials when connecting to the remote machine.